# Call base member method of constant reference?

Tags: visual-c++

My class structure is this:

```
class Simulationobject {
protected:
    std::string p_sName;
public:
    const std::string sGetName();
};

class Lane : Simulationobject {
    //Some irrelevant functions and variables
};

class Vehicle : Simulationobject{
public:
    const virtual void vDraw(const Lane& lane);
};

class Car : Vehicle {
public:
    const void vDraw(const Lane& lane) override;
};
```

I now want to call a function from an extern library in vDraw of Vehicle. It takes a string as parameter `bool externFunction(std::string str);`. The library has no access to the classes and members of my project and just sends some TCP requests, which works fine. My problem is that vs won't let me do that with `lane.sGetName()` . Also `std::string str = lane.sGetName()` won't work, so calling sGetName() isn't valid.

```
const void Car::vDraw(const Lane& lane) {
    externFunction(lane.sGetName());
}
```

Now, I know that you can't call a non constant function from a constant reference. However `sGetName()` is constant isn't it?

Am I missing something? Help would be very appreciated! As a fast and dirty fix, I made `vDraw` a non constant function. However I would like to keep my code constant complete.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const std::string sGetName();` is a non-const function which returns a const string.

The function itself is not const. It only returns a constant object, but as a member function of `Simulationobject` it would be allowed to modify `this`.

What you probably want is this:
`const std::string sGetName() const;`

The `const` *after* the name of the function tells the compiler that the function will not modify `this`. IOW: a call to `object.sGetName()` will not modify `object` itself.

So now,

```
const void Car::vDraw(const Lane& lane) {
    externFunction(lane.sGetName());
}
```

should work. `lane` is a constant object. `sGetName` promises that it will not change the object it is called for. So `lane.sGetName()` is valid.

All this is possible because of the `const` *after* the name.

====
Now about the const before the name:

You declared `sGetName()` as

```
const std::string sGetName() (const)
```

which means, the function will return a temporary std::string object, which is const.

What you probably intended, was this:

```
const std::string &sGetName() const
{
   return p_sName;
}
```

Here you return a reference to a member variable to avoid making a copy of the string. The temporary object above would have to be copied.

But you cannot return a reference to a member, if you want to prevent the caller from modifying your `p_sName`.

So you return a const reference instead:

`const std::string&...`

returns a constant reference to the member variable.

==> no copy neccessary, but no one can change the member variable. The caller can only read the value of the member variable ==> hence the `sGetName` is still a const function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This is actually pretty eye opening, didn't knew that ´´const´´ before a function makes the return type constant and ´´const´´ behind the function makes the function itself constant. Pretty awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call sGetName() you need to change the class declaration of Lane to publicly inherit from SimulatonObject. Also, you need to make sGetName() to be const (if it is).

```
class Simulationobject {
protected:
    std::string p_sName;
public:
    std::string sGetName() const;
    // or const std::string& sGetName() const; // this probably better, ymmv
};

// make inheritance PUBLIC!!! otherwise, sGetName hidden
class Lane : public Simulationobject {
    //Some irrelevant functions and variables
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to write that Lane inherits publicly. The const function was the problem!